# iCloud and in-app non-renewable purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud, non-renewing-subscription

Apple gives developers the ability to save purchases (transactions or receipts) in iCloud.

I have an app. that do that to save the receipts of non-renwable products because the other option available and asked from apple is to implement a user registration managed by my server which is vulnerable against protecting my content (User can spread their accounts to their classmates(30 students) to view the contents they bought).

**Information to keep in mind**

That those are the only available options(at least ones I know) to allow users to view content from their other devices. because apple do not have a restore feature for this kind of products(non-renwable). if you called `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` for this type of products `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` will not be called and only `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` will be called.

> Question - What will prevent users from spreading their iCloud
>   accounts all over the world? user can create an apple account to only
>   use it for iCloud to only move my transactions receipts to it. A class
>   teacher can do it and give this account to his students.

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem here "my server which is vulnerable against protecting my content (User can spread their accounts to their classmates(30 students) to view the contents they bought)." Yes, a user could share their account. Why not limit the number of restores possible with a single account?

Comment: Apple want accept it. to do this limitation.

Comment: Also, you can't get the apple id to do that.

Comment: You have had an app rejected by Apple for placing such a limitation? What do you mean you can't get the Apple ID to do that? I'm talking about having your own server place a limit on the number of restores possible.